# How to clean x-axis labels with many categories

Tags: graph, stata

I am plotting a graph in Stata of two categorical variables. Variable A is binary and variable B has more than 15 categories.

I am having issues with the labels on the x-axis. They are so close together and impossible to read. I have used packages like `splitvallabels`, setting the able etc. etc. but for this particular case it's
s not working.

Sorry if this has been answered somewhere before (I would appreciate the links). `splitvalabels` worked well when varB has few categories.

I have also posted a link to the bar chart that I get with the below code.

```
ssc install splitvallabels  

splitvallabels A

graph bar, ///
over(A, label(angle(45)) relabel(`r(relabel)')) ///
over(B,label(labsize(small))) ///
ytitle("%ge of Households", size(small)) ///
title("Breakdown by region" ///
, span size(l)) ///
blabel(bar, format(%4.1f)) ///

asyvars
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvsf6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `graph bar` the horizontal axis is called a categorical axis, not an x-axis.

You don't give a data example or access to your data, but the form of the problem is a bar chart showing percentages for a 15 x 4 table. For such data, the only satisfactory solution is likely to be horizontal labels for the 15 categories (in your case, it seems, districts of Uganda).

Here is a made-up example. I used `tabplot` from the *Stata Journal*.

```
sysuse auto, clear 
keep in 1/15 
keep make 
rename make A 
label var A " "

set seed 1235 

tokenize `" toilet "durable house" water "living space" "'
forval j = 1/4 {
    gen p`j' = rchi2(3)
} 

reshape long p, i(A) j(B)

label def B 1 toilet 2 "durable house" 3 water 4 "living space" 
label val B B 
label var B " "

tabplot A B [iw=p], subtitle("%") horizontal showval(format(%2.1f) offset(0.4)) separate(B)
```

For your real data, an order not alphabetical is likely to make sense for districts. Similar, a different ordering for amenities might make sense.

Giving people a listing of the 15 x 4 percentages would allow more experiment.

[image]

Comment: Hello. Allow me to express my sincere thanks. This really did the job. Best regards and nice weekend.